# Journey Builder Decision Split on NULL field not reading as NULL

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm running tests on a Journey that uses contact data decision splits as a contact may have done desired action during the course of the journey.  One of my decision splits is looking at a date field that is NULL and sending them an email if that field is NULL.  However, the journey doesn't handle the record properly and puts them down the remainder path.

The other decision splits that look at fields and whether they are NULL are working (but they are text fields).

Comment: Update - the date field is now working.  It's now only the last decision split based on whether an attribute is NULL or not.  It's a text field.

Comment: Update - after further testing...It seems to be working now.  Don't really know if this is an intermittent issue, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you got things working, but wanted to say that I've gotten in the habit of using (Field IS NOT NULL OR Field != ''). I was told by support that empty fields does not necessarily mean NULL.

Comment: This is helpful, no doubt.  I'll likely implement this vs. what I'm currently doing.  I think the major issue here is that Marketing Cloud doesn't prescribe `NULL` on a field that is `NULL` but leaves it blank, causing users to misread a field that is empty vs. a field that is actually `NULL`

Comment: @TomCallahan, One issue among many, I'm afraid >_<

Comment: How do you look for an empty string in the decision split filter criteria wizard? Do you literally put 2 tick marks in the text field? Just a space? It won't accept leaving it completely blank.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach works is to do a IS NULL check OR to check if the field has a space, so it looks like **Field IS NOT NULL OR Field != ' '** (you just put a space in the field, do not put quotes there)
[image]